# Edit parent view controller's title from child

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, iboutlet

I have app with UICollectionViews in UIPageViewController based on [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/) for UIPageViewController, now I've embedded main view controller in navigation controller, and I want to change title of nav bar dynamically when in detail view, but how can I access it?

At first I've tried to embed in navigation controller Page View Controller, but nav bar wasn't displayed.

[image: storyboard]

**edit:** 
I've found out, that I can add navigation item to Time Snap Detail View Controller and set its title here, even though it's not visible in storyboard.

But how can I edit title in navigation bar, when I'm in Page View Controller?(In this case, on stack of the navigation controller is Main View Controller, which has Page View Controller as child view controller).

Comment: have you tried `self.title = @"My Title"` from inside your page view controller?

Comment: hi, it doesn't work, in parent view controller, it's added like this: `[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
    [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];`

Comment: then `self.parentViewController.title = @"My Title"`?

Comment: this doesn't work either, self.parentViewController is read-only

Comment: You're not assigning anything to `self.parentViewController`, just changing the title. That doesn't work either?

Comment: no, I've tried even `[self.parentViewController setTitle:@"sdfsdf"];` with same result

Comment: Any solution to this? I have exactly the same problem! :o

Comment: check my [latter question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443555/uipageviewcontroller-within-navigationcontroller), I haven't tried it though because I used different UI

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, and it's ok:

```
childVC.parentViewController.navigationItem.title = @"abc";
```

Answer (score 1):

The parent in view controller is not working anymore. Looks like the only way is to save the parent in this child view controller's method and set it's title:

```
override func didMove(toParent: UIViewController?)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this. it's working for me in almost same scenario

```
    self.navigationController.parentViewController.navigationItem.title = @"sdfsdf.";
```