# Reloading a DetailViewController that contains a UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipageviewcontroller, viewdidload

I've basically got a Master-Detail app that utilizes `RestKit` to pull data from a remote server.

The `DetailViewController` acts as a data source for a `PageViewController` that has three viewControllers.  My question only deals with two of those so I will focus on that.  I'll call the two important `viewControllers`: `FirstViewController` and `SecondViewController`.

`FirstViewController` displays the detail content of the item selected in the master view,  basically an image and some text.  Scrolling to the `SecondViewController` displays a `UITableView` that contains items related to the content in the main view.  See this link [How to implement UIPageViewController that utilizes multiple ViewControllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641373/how-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-that-utilizes-multiple-viewcontrollers) for an image of a similar storyboard to the app.

To clarify a little more imagine a recipe app in which you choose a recipe to view in the master scene.  The detail scene displays the recipe selected.  Scrolling to the next page displays a table with recipes related to the one chosen.

**With the background established here is my question:**

I am trying to set things up so that a user could select a cell in the `tableview` and the `DetailViewController` would reload with the data from the selected cell.  For example the user sees a related recipe they are interested in, selects the cell, and the view reloads to the main page in the `PageViewController` with the data from the selected cell.

I felt the easiest way of doing this might just be to pass some needed variables into the DetailViewController and call `viewDidLoad` like so.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Grab index object at index path
    NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //Initialize DVC class to utilize variables and methods
    DetailViewController *vc = detailViewControllerId;
    vc.articleId = [object valueForKey:@"articleId"];
    vc.imageUrl = [object valueForKey:@"image"];
    //Reload the DetailViewController
    [vc viewDidLoad];
}
```

This works with one exception:

1. All the variable data is maintained from the from the initial load so when the main screen pops back up I have all the previous data plus the new data.

Calling `viewDidLoad` has done what I hoped.  `viewDidLoad` starts a sequence of API calls to grab the data from the server and then populates the content `viewControllers` of the `PageViewController`.  However I need something that will essentially reload it from the beginning blowing out past data.

Does anyone have any better suggestions to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thanks

**==========EDIT===============**

Here is some more info that may be needed.

Starting from the beginning a user selects a cell in the `MasterViewController` which triggers a segue to the `DetailViewController`.  I am using `prepareForSegue` to pass needed data into the `DetailViewController`.

The `DetailViewController` acts as the data source for the `PageViewController` so when `viewDidLoad` is called in the `DetailViewController` a series of methods is called populate the data source elements required in the `PageViewController`.  Here is the basics.

DetailViewController.h

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
```

{

}

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *imageUrl;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSData *passingPhotoData;  //used to pass to the  pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSAttributedString *passingString; //passes text to pageViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *vc1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *articleId;

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    //There is other things in the method but these are the only significant line for the question.
    //The method call below is to start a call to the server to get the information needed about the cell that was selected.
    vc1 = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    [self getDetailInfoFromServer]
}

-(void)getDetailInfoFromServer
{
    //Here I make a call to the server using Restkit… it is not significant for the question so I'll leave it out.
    //The data that is retrieved from this server call is everything that I will use to populate the FirstViewController which is again an image and some text.
    //If the call to the server was successful RestKit maps out the data in Core Data and I move on to the next method.
    [self getInfoRelatedToDetailView]
}

-(void)getInfoRelatedToDetailView
{
    //The data that is retrieved from this server call is everything that I will use to populate the SecondViewController.
    //The SecondViewController is a tableView and the data retrieved will be an array of images and the associated text.
    //If the call to the server was successful Restkit will again map the data into Core Data entities and I move on to the next method.
    [self getTextForFVC]
}

-(void)getTextForFVC
{
    //In this method I fetch the text from Core Data that was received back in getDetailInfoFromServer.
    //It is all HTML which I parse to a string using DTCoreText and finally set passingString equal to the result.  
    //passingString is one of the variables I use to pass needed info to the FirstViewController.
    self.passingString = parsedString

    //At this point I start the setup of the pageViewController, this is just standard stuff that goes with a PageViewController

    FirstViewController *selectedController = [self populateFirstViewController];
    vc1 = @[selectedController];

    // Create page view controller
    self.pageViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageViewController"];
    self.pageViewController.dataSource = self;
    [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:vc1  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

    //Notice above the call to a method populateFirstViewController That is where I go next.

-(FirstViewController *)populateFirstViewController
{
    //This is a simple method that gets called whenever the PageViewController delegate methods deem it necessary to load the FirstViewController.
    FirstViewController *fvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstController"];
    fvc.imageData = self.passingPhotoData; //This variable was set earlier but I left out the code
    fvc.nodeText = self.passingString;
    return nvc;
}

-(SecondViewController *)populateSecondViewController
{
    //This method is like the one above, it is called when the PVC delegate methods deem it necessary to load the page
    SecondViewController *svc =[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondController"];
    //Here are some of the variables I pass in
    svc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    cvc.detailViewControllerId = self;  //This line allows me to call the viewDidLoad method for the DetailViewController from the SecondViewController.

    return cvc;
}
```

Once all this take place the `PageViewController` appears with the data received from the server.  The FirstViewController handles populating the `UIImageView` and `UITextField`.  Likewise the SecondViewController handles populating the `UITableView`.

Now for the meat of the question… A user sees something they are interested in the table and selects it.  I use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to get information I need for the calls to the server and then need the `PageViewController` to reload.  Given that the `DetailViewController` is the data source for the `PVC`, I need the data source to refresh/reload.  I thought it would be easy to just call `viewDidLoad` to start the process but I'm not sure it is the appropriate way.  What might be the best way to do this?

Sorry for the Novel, just wanted to clarify for those that have put in their input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to pass data back to a previous controller is through delegation. You should have a delegate protocol in the controller that shows the related recipes (in your example), and the initial detail controller should set itself as the delegate. When the user selects one of the related items, call the delegate method, which would pass back the data needed to reload the detail controller.

Now to your exceptions,

1. You get that error because your property declaration is wrong -- it should be,

   @property (strong, nonatomic) DetailViewController *vc;

And in your code you should refer to it with self.vc, not create a local variable (which is what you're doing in the posted code) with the same name as the property,

```
self.vc = detailViewControllerId;
```

It's not really clear what you're doing with that line anyway, since you don't say what detailViewControllerId is.

1. You really shouldn't call viewDidLoad directly. The controller calls that when it loads its view. Since you didn't say how you load the detail controller in the first place, it's hard to say why you get the old data plus the new. What you should do is set the array that you use to populate the table to the values you send back in the the delegate method.

Comment: rdelmar, It appears I was a little to vague on some important points in my question.  I have to step away from my computer until tomorrow evening.  I will clarify some points and add some additional code.  Thanks for your suggestions thus far.

Comment: Ok rdelmar, I've added some code and explanation.  I swear I tried your property definition of DetailViewController and it gave me an error but now it works so I must have had a typo.  I am on board with setting up a delegate protocol for passing data back also.  I also feel like I am up to the task for eliminating the issue of old and new data.  Lastly, I defer to your heroic 38.4k reputation and humbly ask how would you reload the scene now that you see how I do it in the first place.

Comment: @Ben, I'm a little confused as to what call to the server gets the information necessary to reload the detail controller after the user chooses a row in the second controller? Whatever that call is, you should make a call to that method in the implementation of the delegate method.

Comment: Let me make sure we are on the same page.  When you say "detail controller" do you mean the `DetailViewController` or `FirstViewController` in the PVC?.  Assuming you mean FVC the call to get then data needed is `getDetailInfoFromServer`.  So I would just make the call to that method in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.  I think that will work!

Comment: Works as expected thanks rdelmar. Tableview is perfect, but I still have some leftover text from the initial load in the UITextView.  I'm fine with figuring out where I'm holding on to that data.  I was always skeptical of using viewDidLoad but it seemed an easy call.  Not sure why I didn't see what you suggested.  "Fresh eyes" is what my co workers would say… "Eyes that know what the heck they are talking about" is what I always do.  Thanks again.