# Using UIPageController that slides between different view controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm a beginner developer in iOS without any previous knowledge in Objective-C.

How can I use `UIPageController` to slide between different view controllers such as slide to `UITabBarController` for the first page & slide to table view for the second page in Swift ?

And how to change the position of the `UIPageController` & put it on the top ?

I'll be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think this post could give you good info how to do it. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387436/using-uipageviewcontroller-with-swift-and-multiple-view-controllers?rq=1