# Swipe between multiple view controllers using UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, uipageviewcontroller

My UIPageViewController not working at all. What I'm trying to do is switch 2 view controllers inside UIPageViewController. I already followed guideline here but fail. [Using UIPageViewController with swift and multiple view controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387436/using-uipageviewcontroller-with-swift-and-multiple-view-controllers). First view controller appeared successful but when I tried swipe to second view controller it throw this error message. I already set all identifiers correctly.

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

It's cause from here

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier
        let index = self.identifiers.indexOfObject(identifier!) // error message here

        //if the index is 0, return nil since we dont want a view controller before the first one
        if index == 0 {

            return nil
        }

        //decrement the index to get the viewController before the current one
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(self.index)

    }
```

Main.storyboard

[image]

Source code: https://github.com/datomnurdin/RevivalxSwiftPageViewController

Comment: quote of the day: "My UIPageViewController not working at all". same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash occurs while trying to access the *restorationIdentifier* of your view controller. You used `!` to unwrap it but it's nil ; as a first solution, set the *restorationIdentifier* in the storyboard.

[image]

> In general, use `!` to unwrap a value **only** if you're sure it's not nil (by adding a if statement just before).

Comment: It works for me. Gonna submit a PR on your GitHub repo to let you show the result.

Comment: Just submitted a PR on your repo. Tested under Xcode 6.2 (b. 6C131e).