# How do I link an app's tutorial storyboard to the main app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

**Introduction**

I currently have to Storyboards in my project, with one of them being the app's tutorial set in a pageView controller and the second one being the actual app's storyboard. Currently the tutorial only appears on initial app launch (as expected), but I actually have to *kill* the app, and *reopen* it for the main app view to appear.

**Attempt(s)**
I've tried programmatically loading the main app's viewController in the tutorial's pageView controller which *does* work, but is in no way smooth or elegant. The way I did it is similar to the code I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086747/how-do-i-add-multiple-viewcontrollers-to-my-uipageviewcontroller/27097082#27097082)

**Question**
How would I go about fluidly transitioning between two Storyboard viewControllers? What would be the most appropriate way of transitioning between them? What documentations should I read? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest presenting your main view as usual, and (for the first launch) presenting your tutorial view modally. This is a clear interaction pattern; both the presentation animation *and* the dismiss animation will make sense to the user.

Alternately, you can present the tutorial view modally, with animate:NO to prevent a potentially awkward transition.

The code is rather simple. Just load up your main view as usual, and then present the modal view if appropriate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Load main view
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstView"]; // determine the initial view controller here 
    self.window.rootViewController = viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    if (self.isFirstLaunch)
    {
        // Display tutorial
        UIStoryboard *tutorialStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
         UIViewController *tutorialViewController = [tutorialStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"firstTutorialView"];
        [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tutorialViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this when I get home!

Comment: In this case you get warning about unbalanced appearance call in console. For now it it is not an issue, but in future can cause more problems.

`2014-12-09 18:13:40.518 Test[5964:197973] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UISplitViewController: 0x7fc1b041bf60>.`

Answer (score -1):

In this case you get issue about presenting modal view controller (tutorial) from view controller (root), which isn't displayed and loaded yet.
I use direct replacement of rootViewController:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds];
    if (self.isFirstLaunch) {
        UIStoryboard *tutorialStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Tutorial" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = [tutorialStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    } else {
        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    }

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)closeTutorial
{
    // This is solution without animation
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];

    // This is solution with animation
    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:[mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```