# How to add UIBarButtonItem to NavigationBar while using UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uipageviewcontroller

Please forgive me, there are already a ton of questions on how to add a UIBarButtonItem to a NavigationBar programmatically but I just can't seem to get any of the solutions to work in my situation.

Here is the layout of a simple test app I have been working with to learn the UIPageViewController.

[image: storyboard]

I have the page view controller working nicely with three unique viewControllers.  I would now like to set unique `rightBarButtonItems` for each of the view controllers.  I can easily set a common `barButtonItem` in the `DetailViewController` by simply doing this.

```
UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Whatever" 
                              style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                              target:self 
                              action:@selector(doSomething)];    

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton;
```

Given that I need a unique button for each of the three pages in the `pageViewController` I am not able to set the button in the `detailViewController`.  I have tried the code above in  `viewDidAppear` of the three controllers but the buttons will not appear.  I have also tried creating the button in the same way and then setting it like this with no luck.

```
DetailViewController *vc = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton;
```

I know I'm close here, I'm just not sure how to specify I need to add a button to the NavigationBar of the NavigationController that is running the detailViewController that my contentViewControllers are embedded in.  Any help would be great ESPECIALLY SNIPPETS.

As a side note I have tried a few other methods that have come up problematic.

- Setting the button in `viewDidLoad` rather than `viewDidAppear`

  - This will not work because the `viewDidLoad` method is not called everytime you swipe from one page to the next.  The `viewDidAppear` method is however so I am trying to set the button there.  It is possible `viewWillAppear` is called everytime but I haven't checked.
- Setting the button in the UIPageViewController delegate methods

  - This is problematic if the user flips through the pages to quickly the button will fail to change or fail to appear.

***SOLUTION***

It turns out I was close… Rather than creating the button in the UIPageViewController methods I simply needed to create a `navigationItem` property in each of my three view controllers.  When the controllers are instantiated in the delegate methods I simply set the navigationItem property equal to that of the detailViewController.  That way in my `viewDidApper` methods I could create the button.  Then at `viewWillDisappear` I set the button to `nil`.  You can also just create the button at `viewdidLoad` of the `DetailViewController` and change the text and action in `viewDidAppear` of the individual viewControllers.  Here is a sample.

In the delegate methods

```
- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

I call a helper method based on the index of the viewController.  The helper method instantiates the view controllers when it is called.  Once instantiated I set some properties including the navigationItem property.

```
-(FirstController *)controllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{

    FirstController *fvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstPageController"];
    fvc.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    fvc.titleText = self.pageTitles[index];
    fvc.pageIndex = index;
    fvc.navItem = self.navigationItem;
    return fvc;

}
```

Then in the `viewDidAppear` of the viewController I just do this

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Whatever" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];
    navItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton;

}
```

Comment: What is the navItem property on your viewControllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the button to change each time you change the page you look at, it must be done in one of the delegate methods that you have tried. I suggest however, that instead of creating a new button and setting it to the navigation item, you simply change the title.

You can create the button in interface builder and link it to a property in your `DetailViewController` and then call `setTitle:forState` with `UIControlStateNormal` on the button every time you go to a new page.

If you need the button to do something different for each page, I would recommend checking the current page in the buttons action method rather than declaring a new one each time.

Comment: mros, thanks to your answer I was forced to try and make the delegate methods work for me.  After some troubleshooting I realized the issue with my previous attempts at setting the button using things like `vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem`.  I was essentially creating a new navigationItem and adding a button to it.  Due to the nature of the navigationController the new navigationItem will not appear over the top of it.  I then realized I could simply pass the navigationItem property from my DetailViewController to my individual page view controllers through the delegate methods. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can find the correct navigation item to set buttons/titles on by finding the page controller in one of its paged view controllers, then getting its nav item. e.g.

```
UIViewController *pageController = [[self.navigationController childViewControllers] lastObject];
pageController.navigationItem.title = @"My page's title";
```

It's really annoying that self.navigationItem doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues experienced the same problem with page view controller.

As far as I understand, you wont' be able to add UIBarButtonItem to navigation bar of member view controllers in UIPageViewController.  Reason being 'navigationController' is set to nil for UIPageViewController. To confirm, print value of [UIPageViewController navigationController].

However you can do one thing to overcome this issue.  Please download example [PhotoScroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080).

And do following changes in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
// kick things off by making the first page
PhotoViewController *pageZero = [PhotoViewController photoViewControllerForPageIndex:0];

UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:pageZero];
if (pageZero != nil)
{
    // assign the first page to the pageViewController (our rootViewController)
    UIPageViewController *pageViewController = (UIPageViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    pageViewController.dataSource = self;

    [pageViewController setViewControllers:@[nav]
                                  direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                   animated:NO
                                 completion:NULL];
}
return YES;
}
```

And following changes in the PhotoViewController.m

```
- (void)loadView 
{
.....
.....
self.title =@"Frogs";
UIBarButtonItem *newButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Something" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doSomething)];

[newButton setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = newButton;
}
```

To avoid crash, you have to handle UIPageViewControllerDataSource delegate methods correctly in AppDelegate.m

Though, I wouldn't advice you to do above as it breaks the whole concept of UIPageViewController.

I hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Hitesh, thanks for your input but I am going to avoid this route!  You actually can add UIBarButtonItems to the navBar so long as your UIPageViewControllerDataSource is embedded in a navigation controller.  The example I have in my question basically lays the UIPageViewController members over the top of the detailViewController of a Master-Detail application.  This way the navigation bar still remains active.  I had neglected to pass the navigationItem property of the detailViewController to my pageViewController members.  Once realizing this it was a simple task!  Thanks Again