# How to implement Scrolling between views like Twitter App in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

![Scrolling between scroll views with page indicator][1]
http://cl.ly/image/2v2V3T1C2k0z

Can I find anything similar on github?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIPageViewController within NavigationController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21443555/uipageviewcontroller-within-navigationcontroller)

Comment: Thanks! @Amar That's what I want.